# Clicking back button to feed page results blank page

Tags: jquery, html

So when my page loads, it loads the page feed with content, but if you click a link in the feed, then hit the back button after viewing, the feed page jQ methods will not fire, its just blank.

```
 // on document load
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $.post('/index/ajax-feed-items', { pager: $("#js-pager").val(), by: $("#js-by").val(), userFeed: $("#js-userId").val(), ajax: true}, function(data){
         $( ".feedContent" ).html( data );
         $("#js-pager").val(10);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Does that occur in any browser?

Comment: Try using a GET instead of POST - usually POST is used for saving data to a server.  Browsers don't automatically re-POST stuff when you hit the back button.

Comment: Mmm good point.. Chrome only. FireFox and Safari is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per you question it will show blank due to refresh the the page. javascript is a client side language and it flush the content when browser is refresh. if you want to be content remain their... so do that when you post data create its session or cookie and in that bax print session. Now when you post your form to 2nd page there place a code

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
 })
```

Now you data is in session which you have posted from previous page by click on the button and now when you go back data will be displayed to their

Reply if any question or need any detail about this.